# ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the review of a certain product but it returns an error.

My code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\AV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("https://oldnavy.gapcanada.ca/browse/product.do?pid=647076053&cid=1180630&pcid=26190&vid=1&nav=meganav%3AWomen%3ADeals%3ASale&grid=pds_0_1034_1#pdp-page-content")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")
import time
from time import sleep
sleep(5)
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.promoDrawer__handlebar__icon"))).click()

review = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pr-rd-description-text")
for post in review:
    print(post.text)
    
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pr-review-display"]/footer/div/div/a').click()
review2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pr-rd-description-text")
for post in review2:
    print(post.text)
```

It returns: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Can you please tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is really hard to click.

I guess it could be achieved by adding some more waits and moving with `ActionChains` class methods.

I could click it with Javascript code with no problems.
What it does:

1 Scrolls to the Next button

2 Clicks it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')

driver.get(
    "https://oldnavy.gapcanada.ca/browse/product.do?pid=647076053&cid=1180630&pcid=26190&vid=1&nav=meganav%3AWomen%3ADeals%3ASale&grid=pds_0_1034_1#pdp-page-content")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.promoDrawer__handlebar__icon"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pr-rd-description-text")))
review = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".pr-rd-description-text")
for post in review:
    print(post.text)

# wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pr-rd-pagination-btn"))).click()
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".pr-rd-pagination-btn")

# actions = ActionChains(driver)
# actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)  # Scrolls to the button
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)  # Clicks it
print("clicked next")
```

I also rearranged your code, moved imports to the beginning of the file, got rid of unpredictable `time.sleep()` and used more reliable css locators. However, your locator should also work.

I left the options I tried commented out.

Comment: Weird. It doesn't work for me, I still get the `element not interactable` error if I try element.click(), and running your code does not actually click the button.

Comment: @C.Peck Do you see any error when running my code? I just checked it again three times and the button was clicked.  You can verify it if you check the paging.

Comment: after several attempts this works for me:
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)  # Scrolls to the button
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)  # Clicks it

Answer (score 2):

That element is weird. Even when I scroll into view, use actions to click it, or execute javascript to click, it doesn't work. What I would suggest is just grabbing the `href` attribute from the element and going to that URL, using something like this:

```
driver.get(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pr-review-display"]/footer/div/div/a').get_attribute('href'))
```